# HTTP access was forced to visit HTTPS

Tags: apache

I have a few web sites that are hosted in a VPS.

Today, I found that when visiting "http://api.rsywx.com", it forces me to visit "https://api.rsywx.com", and the redirects me to "https://rsywx.net" (which is SSL enabled).

I checked my virtual host files, and did not find out anything forcing this redirect.

Anyone can point me some direction on how this can happen?

Answer (score 0):

Redirects can be done on different ways and levels. Most elegant ways in descending order (my opinion):

- Apache conf (mostly in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)
- .htaccess - file
- in the index.php or the used backend script/code

(- could be even done in the frontend with javascript files but for that the page must be loaded and then will be redirected.. So nothing somebody should use)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I added one line in my Silex application's entry `index.php` to require HTTPS access, which is meant to be locally tested only.